# Need to parse text in iOS

Tags: objective-c

I have some text that contains image links inside '`#`' signs and I need to replace the occurrences of the image links with real images.
so for example:

> The quick brown fox **`#http://mysite.com/images/fox.jpg#`** jumped of the
>   lazy dog **`#http://mysite.com/images/dog.jpg`#**

So this needs to parse into two blocks of text:

```
The big brown fox

jumped of the lazy dog
```

and two seperate links:

```
http://mysite.com/images/fox.jpg

http://mysite.com/images/dog.jpg
```

What can I use to achieve this goal within Xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily replace the URLs with `<img>` tags using regular expressions:

```
NSString *string = @"The quick brown fox #http://mysite.com/images/fox.jpg# jumped of the lazy dog #http://mysite.com/images/dog.jpg#";
NSMutableString *mutableString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:string];
NSString *pattern = @"#(http.*?)#";
NSString *replacement = @"<img src=\"$1\"/>";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:NULL];
[regex replaceMatchesInString:mutableString
                      options:0
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, mutableString.length)
                 withTemplate:replacement];
```

Comment: That's very cool approach, But I am going to need one array for text blocks and another for links

Comment: Will use that in a webView

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way to do it:

```
NSString *sentence = @"The quick brown fox #http://mysite.com/images/fox.jpg# jumped of the lazy dog #http://mysite.com/images/dog.jpg#";
NSArray *stringBits = [sentence componentsSeparatedByString: @"#"];
```

That will split the sentence everytime there's a hash character. After that you can write a method to detect whether an NSString is a link. Check out [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

If possible edit the string in the serverside like use the , as a separator . Then your string looks like this

**The quick brown fox , #http://mysite.com/images/fox.jpg#,  jumped of the lazy dog  ,#http://mysite.com/images/dog.jpg#** . After this use these lines in your code .

NSArray *arr = [str componentSeparatedBy:@","];
Take the strings one by one and check the each string whether it is having the http or not . Based on the the http use the links